# Using NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in Swift 2

Tags: swift, nstimer

I need to call a function [calculatePower(day)] every Xth of a second as in

```
for day = 1...365 {
    calculatePower(day)
}
```

What is the current best practice to do this?

Comment: Is the calculation expensive? You might want to do it on a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this (for every 1/10s):

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(youFuncHere), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Methinks there is more to this. I had tried that. If I use  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(calculatePower(day)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true), or with quotes, I am told that the #selector does not refer to an initializer or method.

Comment: Half the solution is to prefix the function with the name of your ViewController, e.g. ViewController.calculatePower. But I still don't know how I pass a variable in such a structure. Using ViewController.calculatePower(day) doesn't work.

Comment: The above answer is correct if not passing a variable. I'll rephrase and repost the question so it's more explicit. Many thanks.